# How To Log Database Calls in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

In the past I have used FirePHP to log database calls and responses.  I don't want to do this now, since there seems to be a lot of issues surrounding FirePHP and version compatibility.

Are there any alternatives?  I don't particularly need to see the logging in my browser console.  I'm quite happy to consult log files...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Zend_Db_Profiler](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.profiler.html) in conjunction with [Zend_Log](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.overview.html) should work for what you want to do.  `Zend_Db_Profiler` also supports console logging to Firebug out of the box.

Here is a plugin I use that summarizes all of the page's queries using the profiler:

```
<?php

class My_Page_Profiler extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopShutdown()
    {
        $db = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('db');
        $profiler = $db->getProfiler();

        $totalQueries = $profiler->getTotalNumQueries();
        $queryTime    = $profiler->getTotalElapsedSecs();

        $longestTime = 0;
        $longestQuery = null;
        $queries = $profiler->getQueryProfiles();

        $content = "Executed $totalQueries database queries in $queryTime seconds<br />\n";

        if ($queries !== false) { // loop over each query issued
            foreach ($queries as $query) {
                $content .= "\n<!-- Query (" . $query->getElapsedSecs() . "s): " . $query->getQuery() . "\n\n -->\n";
                if ($query->getElapsedSecs() > $longestTime) {
                    $longestTime = $query->getElapsedSecs();
                    $longestQuery = htmlspecialchars(addcslashes($query->getQuery(), '"'));
                }
            }

            $content .= "Longest query time: $longestTime."
                       ." <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"return false\" title=\"$longestQuery\">Mouseover for query</a><br />\n";
        }

        // Log $content here, or append it to the response body

        $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getResponse()->getBody() .
                                      $content);
    }
}
```

For my purposes, I show the profiler information in the page footer when in development mode, but you can easily change the last line to log `$content` and restructure content as needed.  You can also change it to log each query one at a time rather than building an HTML string out of all the queries.  Hopefully this gives you a good working example of how to use `Zend_Db_Profiler`.

To use it, you need to enable the profiler first, and then register that plugin from bootstrap or application.ini.

There are several ways to enable the profiler, which you can see on the [Zend_Db_Profiler introduction](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.profiler.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: No worries take your time, hope it proves helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create your own db profiler. e.g. The configuration for using the firebug+firephp profiler in an ini configuration file will look something like this:

```
resources.db.params.dbname              = "dbname"
resources.db.params.username            = "username"
resources.db.params.password            = "password"
resources.db.params.profiler.enabled    = 1
resources.db.params.profiler.class      = "Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug"
```

If we take a look at the `Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug` it's really quite a simple piece of code, it extends `Zend_Db_Profiler` overriding some methods to implement the firebug+firephp logging logic.

So we can create our own custom logging profiler by extending `Zend_Db_Profiler`. e.g. Our custom profiler might be contained in a custom library: `CustomLib_Db_Profiler`:

```
CustomLib_Db_Profile extends Zend_Db_Profiler
{
    // log db profiling to file logic ...
}
```

Now all we need to do to turn on our custom logging routine is change `Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug` to `CustomLib_Db_Profiler` in our configuration file, like so *(of course, this assumes the `CustomLib` prefix, in this example, in on the include path)*:

```
resources.db.params.dbname              = "dbname"
resources.db.params.username            = "username"
resources.db.params.password            = "password"
resources.db.params.profiler.enabled    = 1
resources.db.params.profiler.class      = "CustomLib_Db_Profiler"
```